# Pass local environment variables to Python script on Windows server using SSH

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, python, openssh

I am trying to execute a Python script on Windows server 2016. I have [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) installed on Windows server. The python script expects two environment variables (`BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG` and `BITBUCKET_BRANCH`) to be present. These are already set by default in the Bitbucket pipeline. The python script is copied to the remote server and then using SSH, i invoke it from the Bitbucket pipeline.

When I was trying the following command in my Bitbucket pipeline...

```bash
scp <copy_python_script_to_win_server> # Works fine
echo $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG   # Prints the repo name
echo $BITBUCKET_BRANCH     # Prints the branch name
ssh john.doe@xx.yyy.zzz.xyz 'C:/Python/bin/python.exe C:/Users/john.doe/deploy.py' >> ./cmd_output
echo $?            
cat ./cmd_output
```

...I was getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/john.doe/deploy.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(os.environ['BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG'])
  File "C:\Python\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG'
```

It seemed to me that the Bitbucket environment variables were not getting passed to the python script (most probably because I was not running it from the pipeline itself but because i was invoking it on a remote server). So keeping everything else as is, I only changed the `ssh` command to the following:

```bash
ssh john.doe@xx.yyy.zzz.xyz 'set BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG=$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG; set BITBUCKET_BRANCH=$BITBUCKET_BRANCH; C:/Python/bin/python.exe C:/Users/john.doe/deploy.py' >> ./cmd_output
```

With the above change, the pipeline shows successful build and the return status (`$?`) always prints 0. Also, `cat ./cmd_output` prints nothing. As you can expect, on the Windows server, the python script doesn't really runs.

Content of `C:/Users/john.doe/deploy.py`:

```
import os
...
print(os.environ['BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG'])
print(os.environ['BITBUCKET_BRANCH'])
...
...
```

I'm not sure what exactly am i doing wrong. Any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are not resolved in single-quote strings.

Try replacing them with double-quotes:

```bash
ssh john.doe@xx.yyy.zzz.xyz "set BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG=$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG;  ..." >> ./cmd_output
```

---

Further your syntax is probably not valid.

- If your shell is Windows `cmd.exe`: You cannot use a semicolon (`;`) to separate commands. You have to use ampersand (`&`).

  ```
  set VAR1=$VALUE & set VAR2=$VALUE2 & python ...
  ```
- If your shell is an emulation of some common *nix shell, like `bash`: `set` command is not for setting environment variables. In `bash`, you set variables simply by an assignment, like `BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG=$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG`.

  ```
  VAR1=$VALUE1; VAR2=$VALUE2; python ...
  ```

Comment: Thanks but for the quote thing, i came across a similar situation before though that time it was all *nix based environment. I think single quote is the [suggested](https://serverfault.com/questions/368327/difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-when-passing-command-through) way although i tried double quote as well after i read your suggestion. Nothing happened. Command didn't run on Windows machine, `echo` returned 0 and output file was blank. :(

Comment: What shell does your SSH server use? *nix-like shell or Windows `cmd.exe`?

Comment: I ran this command: `ssh john.doe@xx.yyy.zzz.xyz "echo $SHELL"` and it returned `/bin/ash`.

Comment: Where did you take `ash` from? Do you have WSL installed?

Comment: I did not install it explicitly. I was just checking if i could install WSL but my server version is not compatible. Here are the details: `Version # 1607` and `OS Build # 14393.2485`. I have only installed [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH)

Comment: But Win32-OpenSSH does not ship with any *nix binaries (like `ash`).

Comment: Yes, i just saw the installation directory. It wasn't there. I am not sure how that was installed. I see [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/DefaultShell) page for Win32-OpenSSH. It says we can change the default shell. Any way i can get this working?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: My bad. I should've changed the syntax after verifying the shell. Thanks. I did that but now when i use your updated syntax, i get `'BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`. I also tried using `export` keyword before but then i get similar error: `'export' is not recognized as an internal...`. I also used them around single quote but the issue persists.

Comment: When you shell is not `ash`, but `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83890/discussion-between-technext-and-martin-prikryl).